# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not “list”) to tuple" - Odoo v9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have this model:

```
class paymentTerm(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.payment.term'

    dte_sii_code = fields.Selection((
        ('1', '1: Contado'),
        ('2', '2: Credito'),
        ('3', '3: Otro')), 'DTE Sii Code', )
```

I want to add some fields to this selection, from another module, like this:

```
class paymentTerm(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.payment.term'

    dte_sii_code = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('1', 'COB1'),('2','COBRANZA'),('11','ACRED'),('12','CBOF'),('21','S/PAGO'),('32','ANTICIPO')])
```

But when I try to apply this to my module, Odoo server throws me this:

```
2016-11-25 02:04:06,338 13570 ERROR odoo_solti_ultima openerp.modules.registry: Failed to load registry
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 386, in new
openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 340, in load_modules
registry.setup_models(cr)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 197, in setup_models
model._setup_base(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, partial)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 354, in old_api
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/models.py", line 3019, in _setup_base
self._add_field(name, field.new())
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/models.py", line 471, in _add_field
field.setup_base(self, name)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/fields.py", line 406, in setup_base
self._setup_attrs(model, name)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0c-20161106/openerp/fields.py", line 1498, in _setup_attrs
self.selection = OrderedDict(self.selection + selection_add).items()
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
```

Any ideas about this?

I think it has to do with the original model, but I'm not so sure

I'm working on Odoo v9 community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Selection* datatype takes *list of tuples*. You have declared *dte_sii_code* with tuples. It should be *list of tuples*

Try with following code.

```
class paymentTerm(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.payment.term'

    dte_sii_code = fields.Selection([
        ('1', '1: Contado'),
        ('2', '2: Credito'),
        ('3', '3: Otro')], 'DTE Sii Code')

class paymentTerm(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.payment.term'

    dte_sii_code = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('4', 'COB1'),
        ('5','COBRANZA'),
        ('11','ACRED'),
        ('12','CBOF'),
        ('21','S/PAGO'),
        ('32','ANTICIPO')])
```

NOTE:

We should care about key. If you add tuple with same key then it will override with new definition.

Comment: Thank You very much, yeah, I was suspecting this, but I wasn't that sure, Thank You again!